# Clips clips.eval("(set-strategy random)") don't work

Tags: java, clips

Why the command

```
clips.eval("(set-strategy random)")
```

don't work?
I have differents rule that can be activated but they are activeted always in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your description which of the following two scenarios is occurring:

1. CLIPSJNI launched once. Multiple runs produce same order.
2. CLIPSJNI launched multiple times. Single run produces same order as last
   launch.

For #1, you have not provided enough information to replicate the issue. For #2, this is the relevant information from section 5.37 of the Basic Programming Guide:

> The random strategy is useful for testing. Because this strategy
>   randomly orders activations having the same salience, it is useful in
>   detecting whether the execution order of rules with the same salience
>   effects the program behavior. Before running a program with the random
>   strategy, first seed the random number generator using the seed
>   function. The same seed value can be subsequently be used if it is
>   necessary to replicate the results of the program run.

So for #2, make this call from your code:

```
clips.eval("(seed (integer (time)))");
```